# Should unused connector terminals be connected to ground?

Tags: grounding, safety, emc, termination

I am using both male and female D-SUB connectors and about half their terminals are currently unassigned, unused and unterminated. They are not the crimpable versions, all the conductive terminals are physically present. The connectors are through-hole and PCB-mounted.

Boxes with chassis grounds are essentially connected together in my setup and the chassis grounds are connected through cable shielding. The signals carried are RS-422 on most connectors (cable length of approximately 3 meters, twisted pairs), except SPI on one. I am tempted to do differential SPI on this specific connector, given the high frequency (over 10MHz) of the clock and the cable length (approximately 1 meter). Power runs through every cable. The cables will be home-made.

How would you recommend terminating unused connector terminals for EMC, electrical safety and practical considerations? Is grounding them the way to go?

Comment: That depends on many things, such as  do you connect two boxes directly, or is there a cable between, what kind of signals they are, and what kind of cable there is. Can you fill in the details? Is power carried through the connector?

Comment: Dear Justme, thank you for your questions, I have edited my post to try to address them.

Comment: You already accepted an answer before adding in the details.

Comment: It would still be helpful to receive further insights!

Comment: It does not encourage to read an answered question or to write a new answer as we don't know if you are going to read them any more and mark a better answer.

Comment: I believe that people who search answers don't just read the accepted or even the top rated answer. As far as I'm concerned, I definetly read all the answers to my questions.

Comment: What d-sub are they, more specifically? IDC, solder cup, PCB mounted?

Comment: Hi Lundin, they are through-hole PCB-mounted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For EMC purposes, you might consider grounding (or VCC or any other RF ground / supernode) to control ground-return paths, or increase density of ground around priority signals.  This doesn't mean too much in generic D-sub connectors and multiconductor cable, but can be handy with twisted pairs or even coax.

Additional grounding can be used to advantage, when constructed appropriately: VGA cables preferably use coax cable for each video channel, with signal and ground connected through adjacent pin pairs, separate from other grounds in the connector.  This leaves some unshielded length within the connector that can introduce between-channel interference, and reduces shielding value (the D-sub itself provides good, but not perfect, shielding, and would be slightly improved with fully shielded coax through the connector, like ye olde DB13W3 did it).  In commercial applications, it's rare you notice anything different: the crosstalk between channels is likely to be a few LSBs if that, and the intensity change in whatever other channels(s) are changing (say in a step response) masks the change in the remaining channels.

If you were designing/building, say, an SPI cable, you'd get best signal quality from pairing MOSI, MISO, CS (if present) and SCK with grounds, though you don't really have choice over where any of them are within a multiconductor cable (unless you get twisted-pair cable) so your improvements are fairly limited anyway.  Such a cable would still benefit from foil/braid shield, and filtering and schmitt trigger receivers (to mitigate the crosstalk developed in the cable).  Also, only SCK really needs great signal quality or extra treatment, as long as the baud rate is low enough for signals to settle by the time the (filtered) SCK edge comes along.  (And maybe something about MISO timing or reclocking on the return trip.)

In other connectors (not D-sub specifically), you might skip pins (leave them unconnected) to increase isolation voltage between positions.  Single-row headers, for example.  This doesn't apply to D-sub, where the distance from pin to shell mostly obviates pin-to-pin isolation.  (And with the staggered arrangement, you'd need to skip several pins to do that, which isn't very efficient.)

Other than that, floating (unconnected) pins do change the capacitance and perhaps leakage between neighboring pins, but compared to the rest of a cable, it's wildly insignificant.  Floating metal can be a concern in sensitive and RF circuits, say on a PCB where trace lengths are short and tight and floating copper can result in increased crosstalk or the like; you're very unlikely to have such a situation, that would also be able to use D-sub connectors.

Comment: Very good anwer. Only Thing I would add is:"if you ground pins, connect them at both ends! Otherwise you're creating an antenna"

Comment: Well, if there is RS422 carried through the cable, in order to avoid ground loops, perhaps they are best left unconnected on both ends?

Comment: @Tommy95 RS-422 is not a two-wire bus. You cannot leave ground reference between devices unconnected. Unless they connect via some other route already. Besides you are running power and SPI as well.

Comment: I meant grounded only once of course, versus through multiple wires.

Comment: That would be a candidate for a twisted-pair cable, sure. With shielding available, I wouldn't bother with RS-422, not for 1m of length (~5ns propagation delay); logic-level will suffice. You may want a buffer or driver to help separate the transient load of the cable from the signal source (MCU?), and some filtering or termination to deal with the cable's response.  74HC7014 might be used profitably with a resistor divider style termination; source-load termination will likely lead to lower crosstalk than source termination alone.

Answer (score 2):

If the pins are not used, I would just leave them unconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning on using these pins in future revisions of the board?
If so, and you ground the pins, then consider what happens if the signal-source board for a new revision of this sink board is connected to the current revision.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I could scratch the traces on the PCB for prototyping. I don't plan on using these pins at the moment.